# Convert to string Powershell issue

Tags: type-conversion, powershell-5.0

I would like to connect to Exchange online using my cred like this :

```
$Username = "bigdaddy@love.onmicrosoft.com"
$PasswordPath = "C:\PowerShell\password.txt"

#Read the password from the file and convert to SecureString
$SecurePassword = Get-Content $PasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword
```

But I got an issue while tryign to Convert to String as Below

[image]

I used .txt file only

[image]

Comment: Add -Asplaintext -Force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `-AsPlainText -Force`

```
$Username = "bigdaddy@love.onmicrosoft.com"
$PasswordPath = "C:\PowerShell\password.txt"

#Read the password from the file and convert to SecureString
$SecurePassword = Get-Content $PasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword
```